# how to send click a button and submit the students details in the database in symfony

Tags: symfony, twig, content-management-system

I am doing a symfony final year project at Kyambogo university in Uganda for clearing students within different departments.
I want to be clicking a button and clearing students.
I want this button to submit details of the student which are rendered in the table from entity Student  to be 
submited to another entity ClearedData
even if you dont do it exactly using my example and you just show me how you could do it using your own example I will be very glad
because all I need to get a way of how I can start on it.
This is my code for the table and the clear button that submits is the one I want to be clicking and sending this data to the database

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}
{% block body %}
<div class="box table-responsive">
        <div class="box-header">
        <h1 class="box-title">Student List</h1>

        </div>
        <!-- box-header -->
        <div class="box-body">
          <table id="example1" class="table table-striped">
          <thead>
            <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>Registration No.</th>
            <th>Gender</th>
            <th>Year Of Study</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th>Actions</th>
            </tr>
         </thead>
         {% for student in students %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ student.id }}</td>
            <td>{{ student.firstName }}</td>
            <td>{{ student.lastName }}</td>
            <td>{{ student.regNo }}</td>
            <td>{{ student.gender }}</td>
            <td>{{ student.yearOfStudy }}</td>
            <td>Cleared/Not Cleared</td>
            <td><input type="submit" value="Clear" class="btn btn-xs btn-facebook"></td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
<tfoot>
    </tfoot>

          </table>
        </div>
        <!-- /.box-body -->
      </div>         
{% endblock %}
```

this is the entity class where i want to be submitting the form

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
* ClearedData
*
* @ORM\Table(name="cleared_data")
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository  \ClearedDataRepository")
* @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
*/
class ClearedData
{
/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="regNo", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $regNo;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="department", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $department;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="status", type="string", length=40)
 */
private $status;

/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="date", type="date")
 */
private $date;


/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Set regNo
 *
 * @param string $regNo
 * @return ClearedData
 */
public function setRegNo($regNo)
{
    $this->regNo = $regNo;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get regNo
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getRegNo()
{
    return $this->regNo;
}

/**
 * Set department
 *
 * @param string $department
 * @return ClearedData
 */
public function setDepartment($department)
{
    $this->department = $department;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get department
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getDepartment()
{
    return $this->department;
}

/**
 * Set status
 *
 * @param string $status
 * @return ClearedData
 */
public function setStatus($status)
{
    $this->status = $status;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get status
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getStatus()
{
    return $this->status;
}

/**
 * Set date
 *@ORM\PrePersist
 * @param \DateTime $date
 * @return ClearedData
 */
public function setDate($date)
{
    $this->date = new \DateTime();

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get date
 *
 * @return \DateTime 
 */
 public function getDate()
 {
    return $this->date;
 }
 }
```

[image: This is the table with the clear button i want to click and clear a student]

Answer (score 0):

Change your input submit and make this :

```
<a href="{{ path('clear_student', { 'idstudent': student.id }) }}">Clear</a>
```

Create a route for the path 'clear_student :

```
clear_student:
   path:    /student/clear/{idstudent}
   defaults: {_controller: YourBundle:TheName:clearStudent}
```

And do your controller :

```
<?php

namespace YourBundle\Controller;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use YourBundle\Entity\ClearedData;

class TheNameController extends Controller
{
    public function clearStudentAction(Request $request, $idstudent)
    {   
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $student = $em->getRepository('YourBundle:Student')->findOneById($idstudent);
```

(here apply like you want the necessary value of your clearedStudent)

```
        $clearedStudent = new ClearedData();
        $clearedStudent->setRegNo($student->getRegNo());
        $clearedStudent->setDepartment();
        $clearedStudent->setStatus();
        $clearedStudent->setDate();

        $em->persist(clearedStudent);
        $em->flush();
```

If needed delete the student :

```
        $em->remove($student);
        $em->flush();
```

and return to the URL you want like target :

```
        return $this->render('default/targetPage.html.twig', array(
        'example' => $example, //If you have some data to send to the targetPage
        ));

    }
}
```

I hope it's gonna help you, but i don't understand you haven't form -> so donc need submit button. And you have some needed value in you ClearedStudent that doesn't appears in the student. So i hope it's will help you :) good luck

WARNING : i recommanded you to update your two entity for make them match -> if the goals it's to deplace one to the other you need to have the same needed field.

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me out it worked out

Comment: how are you, i would like to know how i can use a field in fosuser bundle and then i could be able to give a different view to each student to be able to see his own form for the department he has been cleared, i have not pasted any code for that because i just want to get the idea of how i can generate a view basing maybe on a username as a field in fosuser bundle to generate view for different users, because i really dont know where even to start from and i have nothing worked out yet